# Insert New Primary Key to Table with data already inside

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-server

I have table with million of records and is requirement to add new int field 'Id' as primary key with auto incremental. Now I have manage to do to tables with reasonable small amount of data but some of table holds million of records and throw time out error. The database is Azure SQL

```
'MyTable(dbo)' table
- Unable to modify table.  
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the 
server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: How are you executing these commands?

Comment: Honestly, you might be better off creating a new table, Inserting the existing data into the new one, and then `DROP`ing the old table and renaming the new one. Having a requirement to add a `IDENTITY` column to a table with millions of rows already, however, always has a bit of a "smell" of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me though.

Comment: @David, I going to Designer Editor by right clicking on the table in SQL Management Studio, then Add New column Id and under properties --> Identity Specification --> set to Identity Increment to Yes

Comment: @Larnu, there is no foreign key. I am working on code and know need to come back but I need quick dirty solution .. This is on Staging so I don't mind of taking rick here

Comment: That's why I recommended you create a new version of the table, `INSERT` the existing data into it, and then `DROP` the old table and rename new one, @Toxic. You can also then make use of a `BULK INSERT` if you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make an example code that maybe you can reference:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.doc_exz (column_a INT not null, column_b INT) ;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.doc_exz VALUES (7,7) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.doc_exz VALUES (7,7) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.doc_exz VALUES (7,7) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.doc_exz VALUES (7,7) ;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.doc_exz ADD id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null 
GO

ALTER TABLE doc_exz ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
GO        
SELECT * FROM dbo.doc_exz ;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.doc_exz ;
GO
```

The output of the query:

[image]

If you still get the timeout error. You could follow the suggestion of @Larnu:

1. Create a new version of the table
2. INSERT the existing data into it
3. then DROP the old table and rename new one.

You can use [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the large amount data.